# 403 "Invalid CORS request" after a successfull SAML authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

We are using spring security in our application (SP) to authenticate through a SAML IDP.

As expected accessing to the SP redirect to the IDP authentication form but after the successful authentication, POST of the SAML response to {myServerBase}/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId} in spring security fails with 403 "Invalid CORS request".

In the POST request, there is a http header "Origin: null" which seems to make spring CorsFilter to reject the SAML response.

We have this issue with 2 different SAML IDP we tested (Samling and Okta), we are using spring security 5.4.1

The only way to pass authentication with SAML is to disable CORS in spring security (but we would like cors activated)
Are there any particular steps we would have missed to configure both cors and saml with spring security ?

Arnaud

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No,, unfortunately we have disaled cors to get rid of the issue

Comment: Do you use Jhipster in your application?

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using Jhipster and you see this issue:**

In localhost the origin will be null and you will need to add the below to prevent the browser from blocking the requests.

```
jhipster:
  cors:
    allowed-origins:
      - null
```

For environments other than localhost, you can replace null with your expected Origin URL.